# Create-react-app failing with error: node incompatible with css-loader

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, css-loader

I'm simply trying to create a react app with the command `npx create-react-app my-app` 
but get this error:

`css-loader@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 6.9.0 <7.0.0 || >= 8.9.0". Got "8.5.0"`

I've tried updating node but it seems to not work, checking the version it says 8.5.0 just like in the error.
Even restarted my computer as a last option but that also didn't help..

Is there anything else I could try? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall NodeJS and install a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally realised the problem was my old version of node, I had nvm installed and had to update which node version I'm using with `nvm use node`.

*Update:*

I had to use that command every time I started a new terminal session. Also had problems when some other packages were picking up the wrong node version for some reason.

That can be fixed with the command `nvm alias default 10.11.0`, or which ever version you want to use.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same thing and spent few hours trying to figure it out.  I think it was the webpack.  Finally, I ended updating the node.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed node needed to be updated. For me it didn't work even with that command though.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that

`nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node`

worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Als tried some stuff and after updating the lates version of node with nvm it worked. I got it from this website: https://bytearcher.com/articles/ways-to-get-the-latest-node.js-version-on-a-mac/

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```